# How to restart spider from where it left off?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Example: if the spider throws an exception on page15, it should be able to restart at page 15.

As i went through the Scrapy documentation, under **Jobs: pausing and resuming crawls topic** - I ran the spider with the command as mentioned in the document i.e, **scrapy crawl spidername -s JOBDIR=directory-path**

so when i go into that specific directory-path, i can see that three files had been created namely, **requests.queue, requests.seen and spider.state**[as in the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE7zU.png] i can see that only spider.state is having 1KB size and rest two files are 0KB, but while running the spider, under requests.queue folder a file with name *p0* will be created, but once the spider is stopped and ran again the file *p0* under requests.queue folder is deleted.

As i took a look into document again, it stated "***Requests must be serializable by the pickle module, in order for persistence to work, so you should make sure that your requests are serializable.***" and after making the setting **SCHEDULER_DEBUG = TRUE** in settings.py i can see in console that,

[scrapy.core.scheduler] WARNING: Unable to serialize request:

is this the reason, why i can not resume the spider from where it stopped as the requests are not serialized? if so how can i make the requests serialized and make the spider to resume from where it left off? or is there any other approach how this can be achieved, answers with a sample code will be helpful.
and also can anyone explain what those three files are for as there is no explaination in the Scrapy documentation.

Comment: Can you should the code you are using you yield new requests? Is it possible that the meta field of your requests contains non-serializable data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in order to stop and resume spiders effectively, we should make use of DB to store the state of the spider, there maybe other ways too, but i felt this is the most effective way.